# Is the following: "The people of USA has..." correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I know that the word "people" can be singular to refer to a specific unit, be they nationality, ethnic, or tribe. With that being said, is it correct if I write in my essay:

> The people of USA has

I've consulted dictionaries and all the websites pertaining to English grammar, but not even one gives me a clearer idea on this usage.

Comment: Just because *peoples* is a word, it doesn't mean that *people* can be singular.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why it takes plural form even though it refers to a unit or a group of US citizens?

Comment: If you said "the group of people" you would said 'has,' but when you just say "the people" you are referring to the people themselves, not the people as a singular unit, and so you say 'have.'

Comment: I think the use in the UK may be somewhat different (I'm thinking "people" is sometimes used as "nation" might be), but in the US it would be "the people are".

Comment: I think you can use a singular verb with *people* if it has the indefinite article before it: *"when a people is oppressed ..."*. This sounds old-fashioned to me. (And [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+a+people+is%2CWhen+a+people+is%2Cwhen+a+people+are%2CWhen+a+people+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20a%20people%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhen%20a%20people%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhen%20a%20people%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhen%20a%20people%20are%3B%2Cc0) shows that the plural verb is used just as often here.)

Comment: Mysti Sinha. No, I know the distinction between person and people. What I am asking here is the use of people as singular unit. I don't see much use of "people's" singular form in English language so it's baffling that some find it errant and some find it permissible.

Comment: No, you're asking if the phrase you have proposed is acceptable for an essay. I'm saying that **people** is a plural noun, you cannot write or say for example: **"The four million peoples** *who live in Mississippi"* It MUST be: **The four million people** *who live...*" I've offered a valid alternative with *population* a noun that can be used in the singular and in the plural. The use of *a people* is rare but that indeed is singular, however as this link shows it is more often used as a predicate noun http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00048.htm

Comment: I have no idea what the actual **population** of Mississippi **is** by the way. :)

Answer (score 5):

> [Matching verbs to collective nouns](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/matching-verbs-to-collective-nouns)
>
> Collective nouns are nouns which stand for a group or collection of
> people or things. They include words such as *audience*, *committee*,
> *police*, *crew*, *family*, *government*, *group*, and *team*.
>
> Most collective nouns can be treated as singular or plural, with
> either a singular or plural verb:
>
> √ The whole family **was** at the table. [singular verb]
>
> √ The whole family **were** at the table. [plural verb]
>
> There are a few collective nouns which are always used with a **plural
> verb**, the commonest of which are ***police*** and ***people***:
>
> √ She’s happy with the way the police **have** handled the case.
>
> X She’s happy with the way the police **has** handled the case.
>
> If you aren’t sure whether to use a singular or a plural verb with a
> collective noun, look it up. Most dictionaries will tell you which is
> correct.
>
> <sub>Source: Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

*People* is the plural form of *person* e.g."A person **lives** in that apartment" [singular verb] and "Several people **live** in that building" [plural verb]

Hence the beginning of the OP's sentence should read:

> *The people of the US **have***...
> (note the addition of the definite article, which must precede either *US* or *USA*).

Alternatively, one could use the singular collective noun *population* instead of *people*:

> The population in the USA **has** approximately doubled over the past 50 years, with a total
> population of 302 million (as at July 2007):
> <sub>[Source](http://www.law.unimelb.edu.au/files/dmfile/31_3_5.pdf)</sub>

---

### *A people*

When speaking about a class, a nation, a community or any specific population then the expression **a people** can be used, in that case **a people** is a singular noun because it represents everybody in that particular group, it is an entity, a total sum, a single unit. I might even describe it as a type of mass (or uncountable) noun; however, it is not grammatical to say: *A people of the US is*, instead we say:

> The US *is* **a patriotic people**
> The Victorians *were* **a people** with high moral standards
> The Canadians *are* **a people** who enjoy nature and spending time outside.

Note the verb that follows *who* in the above example is in the plural form, it is
*"a people (Canadians) who enjoy"*, NOT *"a people who enjoys"*.

I could, if I wanted,  rephrase the sentences so that *a people* precedes the name of the nation/population/community/tribe etc. This type of construction is not common, but it is grammatical.

> As **a people** the US is particularly patriotic
> As a people the Canadians enjoy nature and spending time outside
> As a people the Victorians had a strict moral code

However when *a people* is used alone (without specifying their identity) the verb that follows is in the singular. Taken from an American English writing website [Litreactor](http://litreactor.com/columns/20-common-grammar-mistakes-that-almost-everyone-gets-wrong?page=1)

> You clearly understand more on the topic than suggested by the one
> superficial statement I quoted: "Grammar is never wrong or mistaken."
> That's a false statement.  **A dialect is** never wrong or mistaken, and **a
> people is** never wrong for speaking a minority dialect, even if it
> brings unfair bias and persecution against them.

For further details and examples see Longman's [People, singular and plural](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00048.htm)